# Schema.org microdata - virtual product vs physical

Tags: schema.org, microdata

Does schema.org provide a way to distinguish virtual products (like downloads, services, non-physical purchases) from physical products?

Or is there another way to express via schema.org which items need shipping and which are not meant to be shipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you offer services, you might want to use [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) instead of `Product`.

For [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product), only the absence of properties like [`material`](http://schema.org/material) and [`depth`](http://schema.org/depth)/[`height`](http://schema.org/height) could convey that it’s not a physical product (which would be unreliable, of course).

The [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) type allows to use the [`availableDeliveryMethod`](http://schema.org/availableDeliveryMethod) property, which can have a value that conveys that [the product can be downloaded](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeDirectDownload):

```
http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeDirectDownload
```

So you could use something like this if you offer the product as download:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <link itemprop="availableDeliveryMethod" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeDirectDownload" />
  </div>
</article>
```

If it’s some kind of creative work, e.g., a [`SoftwareApplication`](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) or a [`MusicRecording`](http://schema.org/MusicRecording), you could use the corresponding type instead of (or in addition to, percase as [`additionalType`](http://schema.org/additionalType)) `Product`.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.